# How to rewrite this lambda function to regular function

Tags: python

```
result = map(lambda x: dictionary[x], mylist)
```

I am learning lambda expressions and the concept seems to be little confusing. I am trying to understand what this lambda function is supposed to do and rewrite as a separate function. My understanding is that it takes an item from the list and it then get a value from the dictionary...

Below is how I attempted to rewrite the lambda part

```
  result = list()
  for x in mylist:
      value = dictionary[x]
  result.append(value)
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks! how is it looping through or getting all the elements in the list. i tried to write a for loop but it doesn't give the same result.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code.

Comment: You're rewriting *way* more than the `lambda` there. Is your goal to rewrite the `lambda`, or to rewrite the entire line that uses it?

Comment: @Dually, Press tab on `result.append(value)` line.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

```
dictionary = {'a':5,'b':6,'c':7}
mylist = ['a','c']

def f1(x):
    return dictionary[x]

#lambda x: dictionary[x]

result= map(f1, mylist)
print(list(result))
```